# Probability that argmax$(X_i + Y_i) = $argmax$X_i$ where $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are standard normal random variables

Tags: probability, integration

Let $X_i$, $Y_i$ be i.i.d. random variables with standard normal distributions.

How to evaluate

$\mathbb P(\text{argmax}_{1 \le i \le n} (X_i + Y_i) = \text{argmax}_{1 \le i \le n} X_i)$

?

When $n = 2$ the answer should be $3 / 4$. Can one derive a formula for general $n$?

Off-topic: what is the best SE site to ask this question: here, MathOverflow, or Cross Validated?

Comment: Not MathOverflow certainly. These questions are on topic on both CV and Math.se. Just make sure that you do not cross -post on two SE sites simultaneously.

Comment: You didn't say how you came up with the $n=2$ result; here's a symmetry argument for it without calculation: The smaller $X_i$ leads to the greater $X_i+Y_i$ if and only if the difference between the $Y_i$ has opposite sign and greater magnitude than the difference between the $X_i$; these two events are independent and both have probability $\frac12$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: The result for $n=2$ isn't specific to the normal distribution; it's the same for any symmetric distribution. For $n=3$, the numerical results are slightly different for normally and uniformly distributed variables (about $0.644$ and $0.642$, respectively), so unfortunately it seems that there won't be a symmetry argument for $n\gt2$.

Comment: I'm surprised to find that you have to go up to $n=7$ before the probability drops below $\frac12$. (That's for a normal distribution; for a uniform distribution $n=6$ is enough.)

Comment: @joriki I got the $n = 2$ results by some messy integration involving the error functions and a bit of Wolfram Alpha. If I have time I'll put it in my question but I don't think it generalises to bigger $n$. Your argument seems very clever, and I would give it an upvote if had enough Internet points. I am more surprised how much bigger the probability is compared to $1 / n$ in general.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Sure. Why not MathOverflow?

Comment: @Y.Pei The MO site is primarily for professional mathematicians and as such, focuses more on research level mathematics.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Not all research level mathematics is about solving millennium problems and many research problems boil down to simple questions like this.

Comment: @Y.Pei That is true. But the general rule of thumb if one is unsure where to post a question is to post on Math.SE, as discussed many a time in our meta pages. While this question may not be 'simple', it looked like it could be solved in this forum. If it could not be solved, then you may indeed look for other options.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Yeah I agree with the rule of thumb. By simple I mean simply formulated, not "easy".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $E_{ik}$ be the event that $X_i\ge X_k$ and $X_i+Y_i\ge X_k+Y_k$. You want $\mathbb P\left(\bigcup_i\bigcap_kE_{ik}\right)$. The events $\bigcap_kE_{ik}$ for different $i$ are disjoint, so we can add their (equal) probabilities, and given $i$, $X_i$ and $Y_i$, the events $E_{ik}$ for $k\ne i$ are independent, so we can multiply their (equal) probabilities. There are $n$ different choices for $i$ and $n-1$ different choices for $k$. Thus, the probability you want is

$$
n\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm dx\,f(x)\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm dy\,f(y)\left(\int_{-\infty}^x\mathrm dx'\,f(x')\int_{-\infty}^{x+y-x'}\mathrm dy'\,f(y')\right)^{n-1}\\
=
n\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm dx\,f(x)\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathrm dy\,f(y)\left(\int_{-\infty}^x\mathrm dx'\,f(x')F(x+y-x')\right)^{n-1}\;,
$$

where $f$ is the density function of the distribution and $F$ is its cumulative distribution function.

Unfortunately I doubt that these integrals can be solved in analytic form for $n\gt2$ for a normal distribution. For a uniform distribution, however, we get

$$
n\int_0^1\mathrm dx\left[\int_0^{1-x}\left(\frac12x^2+xy\right)^{n-1}\mathrm dy+\int_0^x\left(x-\frac12u^2\right)^{n-1}\mathrm du\right]
$$

(where $u=1-y$), so we just have to integrate polynomials. Here are the results up to $n=7$, together with numerical results for the normal distribution:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
n&\text{uniform}&\text{uniform }\approx&\text{normal }\approx\\\hline
2&\frac34&0.750&0.750\\
3&\frac{77}{120}&0.642&0.644\\
4&\frac{961}{1680}&0.572&0.582\\
5&\frac{1751}{3360}&0.521&0.539\\
6&\frac{21361}{44352}&0.482&0.507\\
7&\frac{2593439}{5765760}&0.450&0.483
\end{array}
$$

Obtaining an asymptotic result for $n\to\infty$ is easier for the uniform distribution. In this case, the maximum will be very close to $1$, and we only need to integrate $P(X_k+Y_k\le1+Y_i)^{n-1}$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^1\left(1-\frac12(1-y)^2\right)^{n-1}\mathrm dy
&\approx&
\int_0^1\mathrm e^{-\frac12(n-1)(1-y)^2}\mathrm dy
\\
&=&
\int_0^1\mathrm e^{-\frac12(n-1)u^2}\mathrm du
\\
&\approx&
\int_0^\infty\mathrm e^{-\frac12(n-1)u^2}\mathrm du
\\
&=&
\sqrt{\frac\pi{2(n-1)}}
\\
&\approx&
\sqrt{\frac\pi{2n}}
\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

For the normal distribution, the asymptotic analysis is more involved. I'll try to work it out in more detail when I find the time, but for now, very roughly speaking: The distribution of the maximum has a peak near $\sqrt{\ln n}$, and $f(y)P(X_k+Y_k\le\sqrt{\ln n}+y)^{n-1}$ has a peak near $(\sqrt2-1)\sqrt{\ln n}$, which leads to a leading factor $n^{-(\sqrt2-1)^2}$ in the desired probability. However, there are also factors of order $\sqrt{\ln n}$ that complicate matters.

Here's a log-log plot of numerical results for the probabilities for the uniform (green) and normal (purple) distributions, together with the asymptotic results (red):

[image: log-log plot of probabilities]

The line for the uniform distribution is the result above, $\sqrt{\pi/(2n)}$; the curve for the normal distribution is a linear fit of the logarithm of the probability to $-(\sqrt2-1)^2\ln n+c+d\ln\ln n$, which yields $c\approx-0.131$ and $d\approx-0.359$.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This is a great answer and I have upvoted it, but my upvote is invisible because I don't have enough Internet points. The discussion about normal distribution is not obvious to me though, so it would be great if you or someone else could expand it or give some pointers (e.g. where the $\sqrt{\ln n}$ comes from). By the way, what is technique you used for the numerics? Is it Monte-Carlo? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Y.Pei: Sorry, I haven't gotten around to this yet but haven't forgotten about it...